# Runtime of following algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, runtime, time-complexity, complexity-theory

A divide and conquer algorithm solves a problem of size n by dividing it into 2
subproblems, each of size n-1, and takes O(n) time to combine their solutions. What is the runtime of this algorithm?

I'm not quite sure how to structure this recurrence relation and determine what the runtime is. Is the following relation correct?

T(n) = 2T(n-1) + O(n)

How can I get the runtime from this, if so?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your recurrence relation correctly describes your problem. To make things concrete, let's say the recurrence relation is: `T(n) = 2T(n-1) + n` (that is `+n` rather than `+O(n)`.

Then, telescoping the recurrence relation (and assuming T(0) = 0).

```
T(n) = n + 2(n-1) + 4(n-2) + 8(n-3) + ... + 2^n(n-n)
     = (1 + 2 + 4 + ... + 2^n)n - (0*2^0 + 1*2^1 + ... + n*2^n)
     = n*(2^(n+1)-1) - 2(n*2^n-2^n+1)
     = 2^(n+1) - n - 2
```

Checking this is correct:

```
2T(n-1) + n
     = 2(2^n - (n-1) - 2) + n
     = (2^(n+1) - 2n + 2 - 4) + n
     = 2^(n+1) - n - 2
     = T(n)
```